# Is there any way to get all the module names and paths registered to requirejs?

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to drive some custom logic in my application based on the modules registered to require, so I am looking for a way to get all the module names and their paths, is it possible? I tried by using special module 'module', but it wont return paths info. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "registered"? Do you mean configured as paths in require.config, or do you mean those that are actually loaded into the browser at a certain point in time?